# Is ctrl-s save universal for save or are there different combinations for different languages

Tags: user-interface, localization, keyboard-shortcuts, multilingual

I imagine that there are different combination, just looking for an affirmation. Or, are we developers really that english-centric?

If I were in Japan, using a word processor on some computer, would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> save?

Are there keyboards where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> doesn't even exist (non-english keyboards)? Most of what I've seen usually has latin + [insert language here] characters, usually overridden on the normal qwerty keyboard.

Comment: I can confirm `Ctrl` + `S` to be the standard combination in German (Howewer, this may be down to chance because "Save" translates to "Speichern". I'll check what the finns do, they have a word starting with "T" for it)

Comment: What is the translation of "save" in German? Answered before I could finish asking, talented!

Comment: It depends on your definition of "universal". I use Command-S.

Comment: In Word, it's `Ctrl` + `S` even in finnish: http://aakkonen.com/sisalto/asetukset/tab0sis/tab0sivut/word_opas/tallentaminen_1.gif so chances are these are indeed international standards

Comment: Found a hotkey list for ms word (with links to translations): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290938/en-us

Comment: In German it would be "Speichern"..

Comment: In Japanese, save is represented in the menu as "保存" [hozon], and is still also Ctrl-S.

Comment: CTRL-S won't save on a Mac, it is Cmd-S

Comment: @fuzzy By ctrl I meant the control key, which comes in a couple different varieties, mac notably has "command" or "cmd", some keyboards spell it out, "control", some have "ctrl".

Comment: I wish it were true. In spanish, 'Save' is translated to 'Guardar', hence Ctrl + G. And Ctrl + S is mapped instead to 'Subrayado' (underline).

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

1. If the application's UI is in English, most people will expect <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save.
2. If you're writing an application that is going to be translatable, you probably want also the shortcuts to be translatable. Shortcut standard varies between languages and countries. Leave this to the translator.

Comment: In Portuguese, translated programs use CTRL + G to save, as in "Guardar" (Save in PT). It's somewhat annoying sometimes, because some programs are translated and others are not, you can't really tell what CTRL + S / G is going to do until you go to the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ctrl- and Alt- are usually passed on verbatim and not subject to IME processing—assuming one is using an IME; I don't know about IME-less JP input methods. But in the basic case where an IME is used, Ctrl-S remains Ctrl-S, it does not become Ctrl-す or something.

Furthermore, menu entries often have a Latin accelerator defined - cf. http://www.marsei.net/tec/tecladoEspWindows.jpeg :

```
addmenuentry(m, "ファイル(&F)");
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: In practice, there will (except for exotic cases) always be a way to enter Latin characters, simply because everybody is so used to them - even the Japanese. So short of mapping variations (dvorak etc.), you are going to have Ctrl-S.

Comment: Especially the Japanese. They have an entire alphabet (Romaji) that contains a decent proportion of the ascii set. They also learn English fairly intensively

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> saves the document. In MS Office it's the same if it's in English, otherwise if it's in Italian, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> underlines the text, while <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + something saves the document. I have no idea why they did this, but it might also apply to other applications and languages.

Comment: Same behavior for CTRL+S in Portuguese, Save is CTRL+B IIRC.

Comment: In italian version of MS-Office, SHIFT+F12 saves the document.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to write. if you want to write a program and want to publish it everywhere, you should decide if you want it to write in only one language or in lots of languages. If you only want to write it in English, every one that wants to use it should change his/her system language to English or at least should support English. In that way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried on my Mac by setting Spanish as my default language. None of the programs I opened used different shortcuts in Spanish than English, although the menu text was all translated. TextEdit was the main program I used to test.

I also tried setting my keyboard to the Dvorak layout (very different layout, still meant for English), Spanish layout (still QWERTY), and French (a & q, z & w, m & , & ; swapped). Even though the French keyboard had the q in a different place, the shortcut was still CMD-Q.

So, it seems the convention on Mac OS X is to have the shortcuts always use the same letters.

However, according to this link, in Spain CTRL-G(uardar) is normally the shortcut for saving: http://www.ixda.org/node/18527.

Here's an argument for basing the shortcuts on the position of the key on the keyboard, but I'd be surprised if anyone actually does that. http://blog.i18n.ro/are-we-supposed-to-localize-keyboard-shortcuts/